# SecureStoreService dll for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, secure-store, credentials

Where I can get Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll for SharePoint 2013 Server?
For SharePoint 2010 version it was located at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll

It is used to read credentials from Secure Store Service, maybe there is a new approach in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you can get it here: *C:\Windows*\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL.

Comment: Vitaly you're right, thanx.